# Python Thrift RPC Not working on EC2

Tags: python, facebook, amazon-ec2, thrift

I am trying to create a simple client/server application using Thrift which is going to be run on EC2.

The example I created works awesome for localhost, but when I try to make the RPC call across two different machines on ec2 (both of which have separately allocated elastic IP addresses), it does not work with the following error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocialQClient.py", line 25, in <module>
    transport.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 150, in open
    return self.__trans.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 90, in open
    raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, message=message)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to <MY-ELASTIC-IP>:9090
```

I have my security group set up for 0.0.0.0/0 for port 9090 on both machines for TCP. I tried UDP also and it did not fix it. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am hazarding a guess that when one of your ec2 instance ("node1") attempts the RPC call to the other ec2 instance ("node2"), node2 returns its internal IP address instead.

Reference - http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal

Quote:

> This last option uses a little-known feature of the Elastic IP Address
>   system as implemented by Amazon EC2:
>
> When an EC2 instance queries the external DNS name of an Elastic
>   IP, the EC2 DNS server returns the internal IP address of the instance
>   to which the Elastic IP address is currently assigned.

And here's some examples which illustrates how dig returns different values, comparing the scenario where you use a machine outside of Amazon to ping an ec2 instance, versus when you use an ec2 instance to ping another ec2 instance:-

> This is the permanent external DNS name for that Elastic IP address no
>   matter how many times you change the instance to which it is assigned.
>   If you query this DNS name from outside of EC2, it will resolve to the
>   external IP address as shown above:

```
$ dig +short ec2-75-101-137-243.compute-1.amazonaws.com
75.101.137.243
```

> However, if you query this DNS name from inside an EC2 instance, it
>   will resolve to the internal IP address for the instance to which it
>   is currently assigned:

```
$ dig +short ec2-75-101-137-243.compute-1.amazonaws.com
10.254.171.132
```

Comment: actually the issue was i was running my server on localhost and no 0.0.0.0. as soon as i made the switch, and called the client using the elastic ip the server is running on, everything works great!